# How can one explain tax laws to another government without looking bad?

Tags: tax-law

This question is tied to [Is it illegal to be in a position to use "varlik barisi"?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/is-it-illegal-to-be-in-a-position-to-use-varlik-barisi)

Instead of adding all the post here, I'm just linking it. Please check it out before the next line.

I don't want them (the 3rd government agency) to think anything negative about me. Even though they accept that I'm not doing anything illegal, they might think poorly of me because I'm benefiting from tax amnesty laws (?). So they might decide that they don't want me in their country.

So how can I explain these tax laws to another government without looking bad? Any suggestions? Is it possible? I'd really appreciate your help

Comment: It probably depends on the government and on how strongly they feel averse to having you in their country.  But in general, employing legal means to reduce your tax liability would not have a negative impact.  Immigration law tends to exclude people who have committed crimes.

Comment: This government is trying to attract people who earn well in certain fields. So that makes me assume they're trying to attract good tax payers as well. If they see me avoiding tax, maybe they won't be happy even if I'm not doing anything illegal?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a legal question

Comment: In any case, a) governments do not think, it is people (sometimes in the employ of governments) who (hopefully) think and b) you cannot control what people thinks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that make sense:

1. **Don't explain anything.** The laws in question are well established and you are probably not such a genius that you are the first to figure them out. The government in question has almost certainly already encountered your situation before, so it has already researched, understood, and taken a position on the law in question. You have nothing to explain except that you complied with the laws of your country.
2. **Hire a lawyer.** If you are, in fact, doing something novel that the other government has not encountered before, you should hire a lawyer to (a) make sure your interpretation of your home country's tax laws are correct; and (b) make that case in a way that the other country will understand, appreciate, and accept.